# Django session scope

Tags: python, django, session, satchless

I'm currently developing an e-commerce website using Django 1.6 and Satchless. I have two applications in my project: `home` and `nos_produits`.

I'm trying to store the satchless cart object in the django session in order to display the related informations in my templates. Everything works fine in the scope of my application `nos_produits` (where I add my cart object to the session) but when I navigate through the application "home" it seems that my cart object doesn't exist in the session, i.e `{% if 'cart' in request.session %}` is not evaluated to true. So my question is what's exactly the scope of a session in django. Is it limited to the application scope where the session is set or to the whole scope of the project?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Found the problem: in my "home" view I used `render(request, myTemplate.html)` instead of using `render(request, myTemplate.html, locals())`

Comment: The problem is definitely somewhere else, because django sessions are not bound to applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown any code at all, which would have been helpful. But I expect the problem is that you're not passing the `request` object to the template context in your "home" view: usually this happens automatically if you are using a RequestContext or the `render` shortcut, which presumably you are doing in the other views.